# I am developing iOS and Android app with Xamarin Forms in MAC. I am installing PCL Xamarin.Mobile, but i am getting error

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, xamarin-studio

The error i am getting while installing PCL. Any idea about below mentioned error?

> Could not install package 'xamstore-xamarin.mobile 0.7.1'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

Answer (score 0):

From Xamarin Developer Matt Ward on the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22605/cannot-install-xamarin-mobile-from-nuget)

> The NuGet package xamstore-xamarin.mobile 0.7.1 only supports MonoAndroid and MonoTouch. It contains MSBuild property files for these two frameworks. You will not be able to install it into a Portable Class Library (PCL) project since it does not have any files that target any PCL framework.
>
> Instead you should be able to add it to a Android or iOS project.
>
> Similarly Xamarin.Mobile from the component store supports Android and iOS projects. It has assemblies for those platforms as well as for Windows Phone 7/8 and Windows 8 (WinRT). So you would be able to add that component into an Android or iOS project but not a PCL project.

Comment: @ManikMahendru As an alternative, if there are certain feature you want to use from the Xamarin.Mobile library, you can visit the [GitHub page](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Mobile) that hosts the plugin, find the native code for the feature you want and add that code to the projects you plan to support, or just use the plugin installed in the native project. Then you can use Xamarin Form's [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) from your PCL project to access the native code. Let me know if you need examples of how to do this.

Comment: Please give me one example code, suppose that i have one button. When i click on button i need to give options having gallery and camera, the allow user to pick image or click image